# What does a "le" mean between subject and verb?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-personnels

I am reading *Discours de la méthode*. Here is the first sentence I encountered in the text.

> Si ce discours semble trop long pour être lu en une fois, on **le** pourra distinguer en six parties.

I tried to translate it into English as

> If this discourse seems too long for being read in once, one can distinguish it in six parts.

I don't see how that "le" works.

Answer (score 9):

It is just an outdated usage to place the direct object pronoun in front of the first verb. Nobody does that any more.

In 21st French we would write:

- ... on  pourra le distinguer en six parties.

According to Grevisse (*Le bon usage*) this was frequent (but not systematic) until the 17th c. when there were two verbs, the second being in the infinitive (this is the case here). Examples they give:

> D'autres aiment la vie je la dois haïr. (Corneille)

> On nous veut attraper. (La Fontaine)

Grevisse gives some examples until the 19th c.  The latest being found in writers who lived across the 19th and 20th centuries.

Comment: I would have said usage rather than fashion. Otherwise great examples.

Comment: @Denis I might have misused the word, I meant it as manner.... but you're right usage is better.